# Given $f: \Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ and a point $a\in\Bbb R$. Prove $lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(a+h)$ if 1 of the limits exists.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

We are given a function $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and a point $a \in \Bbb R$. Prove that $lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(a+h)$ if one of the two limits exists.

So I thought I had to prove :

1) If $lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ exists, does $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(a+h)$ exist, and are they equal?

2) If $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(a+h)$ exists, does $lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ exist and are they equal?

I was thinking about introducing a function $g(x)$ and letting $lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=b$, and $lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=c$, and use that $lim_{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)+g(x))=b+c$, but I'm not sure if you need that here or how to continue.

Comment: Think about limit definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1.) Write down what it means for $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) $ to exist, and what it means for $\lim_\limits{h \to 0} f(a+h)$ to exist. 
2.)Assume existence of one to prove the existence of the other (do it both ways!).

3.)You can prove the equality of the limits by the use of triangle inequality.

If you don't know how to tackle one of those steps then just leave a comment and I'll expand on it.