# Using the defenition of a limit, show this: $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a+h)$ when at least one of the two limits exist.

Tags: analysis

Using the defenition of a limit, show that this is true: $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a+h)$ when at least one of the two limits exist (thus also proof that the other one exists).

The definition of limits for which I got is $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = b$ this is true if with $x\in dom(f)$ and $d(x,a)<\delta$ then $d(f(x),b)<\epsilon$ where  $\epsilon, \delta$ are positive real numbers.

I have no idea where to start here.

Comment: Expand the definition for both limit expressions ...

Comment: See this [MSE POST](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251458/given-f-bbb-r-rightarrow-bbb-r-and-a-point-a-in-bbb-r-prove-lim-x-right?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The two sides of the equation differ by a change of variable: $x = a + h$ ($a$ is a constant). As $x \mapsto a$ means $h = x - a \mapsto 0$ you get the desired equality.

Comment: Can I just simply say this and use this because that makes it quite easy then.

Comment: @R.vW It is probably the point of the exercise to **prove** that you may change the variables.

Comment: Is there any hint on how to do that?

Comment: Use the definition of limit as you wrote it down, and observe that $|x - a| < \delta$ is the same as $|h| < \delta$